# Concatenate items within function that return a list

Tags: r, function, data-manipulation

I am creating a package that has a function which returns a list of several names (`weight_, height_, bmi_`) with each name repeated suffixed by a number from 0 to 50. For example, the function would return a list `"weight_0"..."weight_50"`, "height_0"..."height_50", "bmi_0"..."bmi_50".

How can I nest another function within my function below that creates these new names without having to list them all out

```
myfunction <- local(function() {
return(c("weight_0", "height_0", "bmi_0"
  ))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try `outer`, i.e.

```
as.vector(outer(outs, 0:50, paste, sep = '_'))
```

Comment: Thanks is it possible to incorporate the paste function within myfunction, without creating the outs vector?

Comment: So something like `return(as.vector(outer(c('weight', 'height', 'bmi'), 0:50, paste, sep = '_')))`??

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the following code

```
outs = c("weight", "height", "bmi")
unlist(lapply(outs,function(x) paste0(x,"_",0:50)))
```

Here we paste each element in `outs` to the numbers from 0 to 50. This creates a list with a vector for each of the elements in `outs`, which we then unlist to a single vector.

An alternative (may be faster):

```
paste0(rep(outs,each=51),"_",rep(0:50))
```

Comment: Thank you that's helpful, is there a way i can have this work within myfunction?

Comment: you can simply put the last line of code inside `return()`